# Should I use socket or comport for Bluetooth library?

Tags: c++, windows, sockets, bluetooth, com-port

I have faced a kind of interesting problem of BT implementation. I have checked the windows SDK Bluetooth and they developed an example based on sockets. On the other hand, a BT is associated with a com port?

Is the speed here a limitation for a direct read from a comport? How come sockets don't have the speed issues even if the BT module is plugged to usb port?

Comment: Depends on your requirements and driver used. There is not only MS drivers can run on Windows platform. And Bluetooth is never associated with COM port. It has RFCOMM based profiles which one is SPP but it does not mean that Bluetooth is the same as COM port.

Comment: Interesting, so what other choice do I have? I have just found the socket approach from MS or serial com.

Comment: It depends on your needs.

Comment: You can develope your answer a bit. I am new to BT :)

Comment: The API you have to use depends on what you exactly want to do. If you are new in BT i recommend to use any third-party libray (commercial or free). Cause in fact there are lot of things you have to learn.